# How to refactor "if x return x" statements

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am looking for a way to refactoring this "if x return x" pattern. It seems to be redundant.

For example:

```js
async exampleFunction(a) {
    const firstResult = await this.firstHandler(a);

    if (firstResult) {
        return firstResult;
    }

    const secondResult = await this.secondHandler(a);

    if (secondResult ) {
        return secondResult;
    }

    const thirdResult = await this.thirdHandler(a);

    if (thirdResult) {
        return thirdResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine IMO, as you want the method to stop as soon as you get `firstResult`.

Comment: Less code does not equal better code. What you have is easy to read, and makes sense. Unless you are intentionally playing code golf, I think this is fine.

Comment: I am not playing code golf, but i have a lot of function call with this pattern

Comment: You could probably do `const res=await a() || await b(); return res;`

Comment: YEP, thats how or works

Answer (score 0):

```js
function exampleFunction(a) {
    return this.firstHandler(a) || this.secondHandler(a);
}
```